# Dreamweaver CS6 SSH private key SFTP on Amazon EC2

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there a way to connect to an Amazon EC2 server via SFTP with SSH private key authentication only? I've been busting my head researching this but couldn't find a proper answer.

Basically, I need to edit files in Dreamweaver and enable automatic upload on save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adobe doesn't offer the option to use SFTP with private key authentication with Dreamweaver.

According to Adobes web site you can use FTPS where there is a certificate used for authenticating that your connecting to the correct server and obviously encryption, but nothing about the use of SFTP with private key authentication.

You can read all about what is available with Dreamweaver remote server connect function here:  http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/connect-remote-server.html

You can use Putty's Pageant and FileZilla which I know is a bummer considering the cost of Adobe Dreamweaver (I have it) but appears to be the only other secure option.
You can read about how to use the 2 here: http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto

Answer (score 9):

I have some detailed instructions of the setup:

1. Download Bitvise SSH Client (Tunnelier)http://www.bitvise.com/download-area
2. In login tab, press ‘Use keypair manager’ and import your amazon .pem key. You should finally end up with something like this:
   [image]
3. In login tab set your amazon instance information

> Host: ec2 instance IP  Port: 22  Username: ec2-user  Initial method:
>   publickey – slot 1

[image]

4. In services tab setup localhost listener for FTP connections like below:
   [image]
5. Press Login to connect to the Amazon EC2. If success, it will open the ssh and SFT terminals. You may now close these 2 windows.
6. In Dreamweaver, setup a new server to connect to bitwise 127.0.0.1 listener. You can set the Root Directory of the FTP.
   [image]
7. Now when you put files to ‘Amazon Test’ they will be directed to your amazon EC2 instance, in selected Root Directory above.

Comment: What about for mac users

Answer (score 4):

I see this is an old post, but I just ran into this issue. I have been using an app that has the same issue for years, my solution was to use Bitvise Tunnelier (http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) it allows you to connect to ssh with your key pair and it will proxy FTP to localhost on whatever port you set. So in Dreamweaver you connect to localhost at that port with regular FTP. It's secure enough for most cases because Tunnelier will not accept connections from anything but local.

The download page on their site can be a pain to find, it is here: http://www.bitvise.com/download-area . You will want "Download Bitvise SSH Client (Tunnelier)".

Comment: This worked like a charm.
Setup your sftp connection via Bitvise "Login" tab, than configure proxy via "Services" tab.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply allow password authentication on your EC2 instance (which is disabled by default) by looking at the following instructions

http://bensnotepad.com/enable-password-access-to-your-amazon-ec2-linux-instance